# Getting linq to use multiple criteria in the where clause

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a linq statement that works correctly if i do this

```
Dim mList = From w In oS
            Where w.Active = True
            Select w

Dim mlist2 = From w In mList
             Where w.EmployeeID <> 19
             Select w

Dim mlist3 = From w In mlist2
             Where w.EmployeeID <> 20
             Select w
```

I'd like to combine them into one statement but can't get it worked out. This does not work, it filters out so that `w.Active = true` but the `EmployeeID` of 19 and 20 are not getting filtered out.

```
Dim mList = From w In oS
            Where w.Active = True AndAlso (w.EmployeeID <> 19 Or w.EmployeeID <> 20)
            Select w
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong: `w.EmployeeID <> 19 AndAlso w.EmployeeID <> 20` is what you want.

Comment: `w.EmployeeID <> 19 Or w.EmployeeID <> 20` is ALWAYS true since no number is both 19 AND 20.

Comment: wow.. makes since now.. Employee is not 19 and also not 20. only a little embarrassed

Answer (score 0):

You need to add where caluse for each statement.

Dim mList = From w In oS
            Where w.Active = True AndAlso (w.EmployeeID <> 19 Or w.EmployeeID <> 20)
            Select w